# installation of libevent development libraries in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, installation, ubuntu-10.10, libevent

I am using ubuntu 10.10 trying to install libevent development libraries libevent1 and libevent2. I used the below command-

```
apt-get install libevent-dev libevent1-dev

But it shows-
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libevent1-dev
```

Then i used- `apt-get install libevent-dev`
But it says libevent-dev is already a newest version. Is that libevent2?
I'm a root user. Am I doing anything wrong? Does ubuntu 10.10 support libevent2? Really appreciate your help. Thanks

Answer (score 48):

Yes, libevent-dev installs libevent2. If you check what apt-get says when it installs it:

```
apt-get install libevent-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libevent-core-2.0-5 libevent-extra-2.0-5 libevent-openssl-2.0-5 libevent-pthreads-2.0-5
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libevent-core-2.0-5 libevent-dev libevent-extra-2.0-5 libevent-openssl-2.0-5 libevent-pthreads-2.0-5
```

Notice the 2.0.x versions of libevent.