# Trying to install an old python app, getting a libevent error

Tags: python, libevent

There is an old python app that I want to install on ubuntu.

When I run:

```
python setup.py install
```

I get this error:

```
/tmp/easy_install-s6CQJl/event-0.4.2/setup.py:23: UserWarning: Could not find libevent
  warnings.warn("Could not find libevent")
event.c:4:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
```

I have installed

```
build-essential
python-setuptools
libevent-dev
```

Is there something else I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
event.c:4:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
```

It looks like you need the Python development headers. Try

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

**Edit:**

[Hookbox](https://hookbox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) can be successfully installed on Ubuntu 18.04 with a relatively modern Python 2.7. Here's a complete installation process:

1. Install OS-level dependencies

   ```shell
   sudo add-apt-repository universe  # Required for old libevent
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install \
       build-essential \
       libevent1-dev \
       libevent-1.4-2 \
       python \
       python-dev \
       python-setuptools
   ```
2. Clone the source code somewhere convenient

   ```
   git clone git://github.com/hookbox/hookbox.git
   ```
3. Install Hookbox

   ```shell
   cd hookbox

   # Ideally we should install Hookbox in a virtualenv
   #
   # Here is one way to do that
   sudo apt-get install virtualenv
   virtualenv env
   source env/bin/activate

   python setup.py install
   ```

   If you use the virtualenv method outlined above you'll be able to run `hookbox --help` to see that it's working.

   You can exit the virtualenv with `deactivate` (and still run `hookbox` by providing an absolute path to `path/to/hookbox/env/bin/hookbox`) and re-enter it with `source path/to/hookbox/env/bin/activate`, at which point `hookbox` should be on your `$PATH`.

   If you choose not to use a virtualenv you'll need to use `sudo python setup.py install` here. That's not recommended as you'll be mixing manually installed Python packages with OS-supplied ones.

Comment: from what I understand that gets installed when I do ```apt-get install libevent-dev``` as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21623535/installation-of-libevent-development-libraries-in-ubunutu

Comment: https://hookbox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#installation is the app, it is maybe 10 years old :(    So yes an older version of libevent I would assume?

Comment: Python 2.5.2 is on the server when I do python --version

Comment: The issue appears to be that the [`event` Python module](https://pypi.org/project/event/) won't build, likely due to its [documented dependency on `libevent` 1.4.x](https://github.com/jaraco/pyevent#pyevent). For comparison, my OS-provided `libevent` is at version 2.1.8. I haven't been able to get this to build yet, but Ubuntu has a [`libevent-1.4-2` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libevent-1.4-2). Maybe installing that will work? I'll try it myself in a VM when I get a moment.

Comment: @Blankman, I got it working on an Ubuntu 18.04 VM. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Chris, I'm not going to set your question as answered, I will create a bounty and then award you more points b/c I really appreciate your help!

Comment: That's very kind, @Blankman. Thanks! It would have bugged me not to solve this one, though :-).

Comment: Thanks for the bounty, @Blankman. I'm glad you found this answer so helpful.

Comment: np!  I noticed during the build I was getting allot of warnings, maybe I should drop down to 2.5.